# adding fading color & transparency to UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, quartz-core

I know how to create and animate a view like the one in the Share sub view of the new app store app that comes with iOS 6+ (see attached screenshot), but I don't know how to add that nice **coloring effect with transparency** on this view.
anyone can provide a code sample to make a `UIView` looks exactly the one in the screenshot?

P.S. the `alpha` property alone of UIView does not do such thing.

[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can add this method to a UIView category and reuse as needed.
It applies a linear black gradient from "theColor" to transparent to the given view.

You should have QuartzCore.framework in your project in order to use the CAGradientLayer object.

```
+ (void)addLinearGradientToView:(UIView *)theView withColor:(UIColor *)theColor transparentToOpaque:(BOOL)transparentToOpaque
{
    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];

    //the gradient layer must be positioned at the origin of the view
    CGRect gradientFrame = theView.frame;
    gradientFrame.origin.x = 0;
    gradientFrame.origin.y = 0;
    gradient.frame = gradientFrame;

    //build the colors array for the gradient
    NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       (id)[theColor CGColor],
                       (id)[[theColor colorWithAlphaComponent:0.9f] CGColor],
                       (id)[[theColor colorWithAlphaComponent:0.6f] CGColor],
                       (id)[[theColor colorWithAlphaComponent:0.4f] CGColor],
                       (id)[[theColor colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3f] CGColor],
                       (id)[[theColor colorWithAlphaComponent:0.1f] CGColor],
                       (id)[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor],
                       nil];

    //reverse the color array if needed
    if(transparentToOpaque)
    {
       colors = [[colors reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
    }

    //apply the colors and the gradient to the view
    gradient.colors = colors;

    [theView.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
}
```

Please note that you should have the backgroundColor of theView set to clearColor so that it doesn't interfere with the gradient. 
Also, for the results shown in the screenshot, the transparentToOpaque flag should be YES.

Comment: I have done what you said exactly but the code has no effect, I called the method like this in viewDidLoad: [UIView addLinearGradientToView:self.testView withColor:[UIColor redColor] transparentToOpaque:YES]; of course I created the category without problems. I'm testing on iOS 6 simulator and QuartzCore framework is also added and imported to this View's page.

Comment: I forgot to set the layer's origin to (0,0). I've edited the post to reflect the change. 
You can play around with the alpha components in the colors array to give a "non linear" gradient if you want.

Comment: Nice tip: Please note that you should have the backgroundColor of theView set to clearColor!

Answer (score 6):

Here is PedroSilva's solution translated to Swift if anyone needs it (added vertical option as well)

```
class func addLinearGradientToView(view: UIView, colour: UIColor, transparntToOpaque: Bool, vertical: Bool)
{
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    let gradientFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)
    gradient.frame = gradientFrame

    var colours = [
        colour.CGColor,
        colour.colorWithAlphaComponent(0.9).CGColor,
        colour.colorWithAlphaComponent(0.8).CGColor,
        colour.colorWithAlphaComponent(0.7).CGColor,
        colour.colorWithAlphaComponent(0.6).CGColor,
        colour.colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5).CGColor,
        colour.colorWithAlphaComponent(0.4).CGColor,
        colour.colorWithAlphaComponent(0.3).CGColor,
        colour.colorWithAlphaComponent(0.2).CGColor,
        colour.colorWithAlphaComponent(0.1).CGColor,
        UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    ]

    if transparntToOpaque == true
    {
        colours = colours.reverse()
    }

    if vertical == true
    {
        gradient.startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPointMake(1, 0.5)
    }
    gradient.colors = colours
    view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: 0)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
CAGradientLayer *layer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
layer.frame = yourView.bounds;
UIColor *blackColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.42f alpha:1.0f];
UIColor *clearColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.42f alpha:0.0f];
layer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)clearColor.CGColor, (id)blackColor.CGColor, nil];
[myView.layer insertSublayer:layer atIndex:0];
```

Where `layer` is the layer of your view.

Comment: this sample produces this crash: [CALayer setColors:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: What is the Class of your view object?

Comment: my view is simply a subclass of UIView

Comment: your updated code give me this color on the subview: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57066689/mySubView.jpg the sub view has the button with text "test". i put some alpha but it is still far from the above glossy view

Comment: and as @Bird suggested use `myView.opaque = NO;`

Comment: Try to play with colors. For example, use: UIColor *blackColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.3f alpha:0.7f];
UIColor *clearColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.7f];

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use a semi transparent png as a background to get the effect like this. Make sure you set the UIView's `opaque` to `NO` and you will be fine.

Comment: Good answer and easy. Also, the PNG can be small such as 10x10(or even 1x1) and then tiled so it doesn't weigh alot.

Answer (score 3):

There is no magic needed for this effect to be achieved. 
You should do it like Apple does it. UIImageViews with small, stretched images.

This view (the bottom-half square that includes the icons) uses an image that stretches and produces this effect.

You should follow this method too. Your views will be very light and it will just cost you a few tests in Photoshop to achieve the correct effect.

As I have noticed, Apple never uses gradient layers on the iPhone. It must be significantly more GPU consuming because it would have saved them a lot of images...

Here's a similar image to test with. 
[image]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You just **need to set the view's background color's alpha value** to your desired value.

[See attached zip code. Go to AlphaViewController's nib file and see it there](http://www.4shared.com/zip/F_pBkEFW/Alpha.html)

I have only set the alpha value for the subview to 70%. You can do it according to your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

In Case if anyone need **Swift 3.X**

```
func addLinearGradientToView(view: UIView, colour: UIColor, transparntToOpaque: Bool, vertical: Bool)
    {
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        let gradientFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height)
        gradient.frame = gradientFrame

        var colours = [
            colour.cgColor,
            colour.withAlphaComponent(0.9).cgColor,
            colour.withAlphaComponent(0.8).cgColor,
            colour.withAlphaComponent(0.7).cgColor,
            colour.withAlphaComponent(0.6).cgColor,
            colour.withAlphaComponent(0.5).cgColor,
            colour.withAlphaComponent(0.4).cgColor,
            colour.withAlphaComponent(0.3).cgColor,
            colour.withAlphaComponent(0.2).cgColor,
            colour.withAlphaComponent(0.1).cgColor,
            UIColor.clear.cgColor
        ]

        if transparntToOpaque == true
        {
            colours = colours.reversed()
        }

        if vertical == true
        {
            gradient.startPoint =  CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
            gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
        }
        gradient.colors = colours
        view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    }
```

Other way in **Swift 3.x**

```
let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
gradient.frame = view.bounds
gradient.colors = [UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor]
view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
```